# Knockout not create and observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxFY9/) shows a list of users being mapped to a function, in that function an observableArray is created surrounding the Roles. For some reason the console log of these mapped users only shows the Roles as and array.

I don't know why?!

```
var userModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    self.LastName = data.LastName;
    self.Email = data.Email;
    self.ContactTel = data.ContactTel;
    self.ContactMob = data.ContactMob;
    self.Username = data.Username;
    self.Roles = ko.observableArray(data.Roles);
};
```

Mapping:

```
self.users = ko.observableArray([]).map(model, userModel);
```

My observableArray extension:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.map = function (data, Constructor) {
    var mapped = $.each(data, function (i, e) { return new Constructor(e); });

    this(mapped);

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $.each when you should be using $.map

```
ko.observableArray.fn.map = function (data, Constructor) {
    var mapped = $.map(data, function (i, e) { return new Constructor(e); });   
    this(mapped);   
    return this;
};
```

Also have a look at the mapping plugin. Dont reinvent the wheel

Comment: I've used each all the time, never had this problem ever.

Comment: The return value of the callback used with $.each is only used to break or continue the iterator. $.map is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/5dXC3/1. Moreover $.each return the orginal object/array sent into $.each for a fluent syntax approuch